# How to decode a base64 string (with binary values)

Tags: javascript, binary, base64, decode

I'm developing a website in Javascript. I've already made the backend using a REST api. To login on the server I have to decode a base64 string. Once decoded it should be just a binary string (not a simple text string, a **binary** string)

The problem is that when I do

```
function base64_decode(string) {
   return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(string), function(c) {
      return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
   }).join(''));
}
```

I have this error : `URIError: URI malformed`.
In addition with `atob` and `btoa` I've had wrong base64 strings.

I've tried many different algorithms, with many different packages and it still does not work. Is it possible in Javascript to decode a base64 encoded **binary** string ?

I've used the same thing for the iOS application and with Swift it works fine. It works also fine in Java. I just struggle with Javascript on the base64 decoding.

An example of a string I'm trying to decode 
`lYlRMvG3MuhOqjmCPAHnoQmEH/TS087iZj9zt6vMG+nJhRsaqr/oTw+drfM+KAEx1xwWbFu6WGB8uEyKPZLb7n9f5mToKiLf8gVVBpogGsI8/EYz3xsxSbLjLby8+FSLNYV8HA4Ct6N5oGEVyM58CY+HwuKZ0T6k7r+t1NDU584=`

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the input string?  Sometimes these strings are encoded as a blob ("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...")

Comment: Just updated the post to include a base64 string example

Comment: When you mentioned binary string, meaning that this contains binary data.  In my experience you can only do this in JavaScript with the use of Blobs.  You can refer to this the following link for additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/1640090  Good luck!